# How to run Grails Wrapper (grailsw) behind a proxy?

Tags: grails, proxy

I tried to run `grailsw`, but the wrapper cannot connect to download `grails-2.2.1-download.zip` (creates a 0 byte file instead).

I need to use a proxy server to connect to the internet, where do I configure proxy settings for the Grails Wrapper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After running `grails wrapper`, your project directory has a new subdirectory called `wrapper`, with a file `grails-wrapper.properties`. You can configure your proxy settings in there, with the following properties:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=
systemProp.http.proxyPort=
systemProp.http.proxyUser=
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=
```

Comment: Note: if a previous call to `grailsw` has failed due to connection problems, be sure to remove the empty ZIP file that has been created. If you leave it there, `grailsw` will not attempt to download it again and instead try to read the file, which of course fails. The file is located at `~/.grails/wrapper`.

Comment: When I ran into this issue with Grails 2.3.5 I did not need to remove the empty file. After fixing the proxy settings the next download attempt worked properly.

Comment: Today for me this file was `./grailsWrapper/grails-wrapper.properties`

Comment: Could we use environment variables in this file? Seemingly, it doesn't support environment variables at least for my case.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem for myself.
It is a two step process

1.a) Back up your JRE_HOME\lib\security folder. This is essential because the below steps might corrupt cacerts file under jre.

1.b) You need to install the ssl public key of Github.com to your local file system. To do that you have to use the InstallCert.java program( [Link to InstallCert.java](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target)  )

It is supposed to be run as java InstallCert github.com
  and when it asks to enter cert number you need to enter 1
  It will create a file with name "jssecacerts" in the current directory

1.c) But this program will not work because it does not know about how to authenticate with proxy. For this you need the code from [SSLSocketClientWithTunneling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/samples/sockets/client/SSLSocketClientWithTunneling.java) page

Use the above two and create a program that tunnels through the proxy retrieves the ssl key and writes a file called jssecerts

2) Update your grails.bat with addtional options. Add these options to the %JAVA_EXE% command line. Paste them after %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS%

-Dhttp.proxyHost=YourproxyURL -Dhttp.proxyPort=YourproxyPort -Dhttps.proxyHost=YourproxyURL -Dhttps.proxyPort=YourproxyPort  -Dhttp.proxyUser=YourProxyUserID -Dhttp.proxyPassword=YourProxyPassword -Dhttps.proxyUser=YourProxyUserID -Dhttps.proxyPassword=YourProxyPassword -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path-to-your-jssecacerts-created-in-step-1